# DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 1 and p in Entity, line

Tags: php, domdocument, phpword

This code fetches a service request from the database, retrieves the request data and service information. It uses an HTML template and replaces placeholders with actual data. Then, it generates a Word document using PHPWord library and downloads it to the user's device.

```
 $serviceRequest = ServiceRequest::findOrFail($id);
    $data = $serviceRequest->request_data;
    $service = $serviceRequest->service;
    $templateContents = $service->request_form_template;
    $html = $templateContents;
//  $dom = new \DOMDocument();
//    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $html = str_replace('{{' . $field . '}}', $value, $html);
    }
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
    $tempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phpword_');
    $phpWord->save($tempFilePath );
    return response()->download($tempFilePath, 'ServiceRequest.docx')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

When a user uploads a template using a WYSIWYG editor, there may be cases where the saved template is invalid and throws an error. To ensure a smooth user experience and avoid any problems related to missing tags, i need filter out these missing tags and proceed with the download. In simpler terms, i need to identify any missing tags in the template and fix them automatically before allowing the user to download the template.
what i have tried is using

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

But it did not work.